# Baffled by ignored CSS file

Tags: html, css

A ridiculously simple bit of web coding is failing to work for me, and for the life of me I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

This is my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Experiment</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet/css" type="text/css" href="/team/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="user_box">
       <p>Hi.  Whassup?</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the CSS file it's linking to:

```
#user_box {
    position: fixed; 
    left: 10px; 
    top: 10px; 
    padding: 5px;
    z-index: 100; 
    height: 40em; 
    width: 16em;
    background-color: white;
    border: solid black;
}
```

It doesn't work.  The CSS formatting is ignored entirely.  However, when I copy the content of `#user_box` into a `style=` tag, it works exactly the way I think it should.

I'm confirming that the CSS file is where it should be and the browser can see it; when I view the source, I can click that link, and it downloads just fine.

I suspect I'm missing something obvious/stupid, but I'm failing to figure out what it is.  I beg you, point out my stupid and get a shiny shiny check mark.

Comment: Run a web debugging tool like the chrome profiler or Fiddler and make sure it's finding the css file, and not 404'ing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct `rel` for a stylesheet is simply `stylesheet`, not `stylesheet/css`. Remove that `/css` and all should be fine.

Comment: THANK YOU.  I may now move on with my life.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `rel="stylesheet/css"`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the tag to have:

```
rel="stylesheet"
```

i.e.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/team/css/style.css">
```

Make sure that `team` is a root folder in your *web* directory and that it has a subdirectory of `css` with a `style.css` file

Comment: Kolink gets the quick-draw checkmark, but thank you, this is indeed the correct answer.